# DE Exclusion on Send Throttle

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

If I exclude a DE that runs hourly, my Send Throttle will include the new added users or it only excludes the ones that were there previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference this help doc: '[What Happens When You Click Send](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_what_happens_when_you_click_send.htm&type=5)'. The audience file is built at step 4 before the sending, so if you were to change the audience source, or suppression it will not reflect in the next step when sending occurs

Answer (score 1):

Do not edit or alter a targeted or excluded DE during a send.  This will result in undesirable behavior, and/or a Partial Send Failure.